# trying to create custom woocomerce email not working from within a plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So I am trying to create a custom email for my woocommerce store, that I can use as a payment reminder.
I put everything together as follows:
one "custom-payment-reminder.php" file, content as follows:

```
<?php
/**
 * Payment reminder Email
 *
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates\Emails
 * @version 3.7.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

class WC_Custom_Payment_Reminder_Email extends WC_Email {
    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->id = 'custom_payment_reminder';
        $this->title = __('Payment Reminder', 'your-textdomain');
        $this->description = __('This is a custom payment reminder email.', 'your-textdomain');

        $this->template_html = 'emails/custom-payment-reminder-html.php';
        $this->template_plain = 'emails/plain/payment-reminder.php';

        // Call parent constructor
        parent::__construct();

        // Other settings like 'enabled', 'recipient', etc. can be added here
    }
    public function get_default_subject() {
        return __( 'Zahlungserinnerung Ihrer Bestellung #{order_number} bei {site_url}' );
    }
    /**
     * Trigger function to send the custom payment reminder email.
     *
     * @param int $order_id Order ID.
     */
    public function trigger($order_id) {
        // Get the order object
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
        
        // Set the email recipient(s)
        if ( is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
            $this->object = $order;
            $this->recipient = $order->get_billing_email();
            $this->placeholders['{order_date}']   = wc_format_datetime( $this->object->get_date_created() );
            $this->placeholders['{order_number}'] = $this->object->get_order_number();
        }
        
        // Optionally, you can set additional email headers or parameters
        $this->send($this->get_recipient(), $this->get_subject(), $this->get_content(), $this->get_headers(), $this->get_attachments());
    }
            /**
         * Get content html.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function get_content_html() {
            return wc_get_template_html(
                $this->template_html,
                array(
                    'order'              => $this->object,
                    'email_heading'      => $this->get_heading(),
                    'additional_content' => $this->get_additional_content(),
                    'sent_to_admin'      => false,
                    'plain_text'         => false,
                    'email'              => $this,
                )
            );
        }

}
```

Then I put an html template for the email in my child theme at woocommerce/emails/custom-payment-reminder-html.php". The content of that file shouldn't be important for this issue as it is identical in both cases.

Next I put the following lines in my functions.php:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_classes', 'add_custom_email_class');

function add_custom_email_class($email_classes) {
    require_once(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/emails/custom-payment-reminder.php');

    // Add your custom email class
    $email_classes['WC_Custom_Payment_Reminder_Email'] = new WC_Custom_Payment_Reminder_Email();
    return $email_classes;
}
```

And there you go, this works just fine. If I check at woocommerce -> settings -> email I can find the template, and when I click on it I can configure it and at the bottom under "html template" the path to the html template is shown.

Now comes the problem:
I created a folder in the plugin folder, and created a new file containing the lines from the functions.php (see above). I moved the custom-payment-reminder.php file to the includes folder with that plugin folder and changed the path to the html template file to:
       `$this->template_html = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/emails/custom-payment-reminder-html.php';`
After activating the plugin the mail again show fine under woocommerce settings, but when clicking on it, at the bottom under "html template" it says **"file not found".**

I tried changing the path to the html template file, but still the template file can't be found for some reason.
Anyone got a clue where to look for the error?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Update:
If from the plugin, I load the file with the email class from the child theme directory, it works!
Now the question is why? I is probably something about the path to the html template, but I can't figure out what the problem is :-(
It probably needs to be specified relative to the file calling it?

Moving functionality from the functions.php to a separate plugin.
Accessing files does not work anymore

Comment: Alright it boils down to the following difference in the file that includes the email class:
If the file sits in the child theme folder under woocommerce/mails and the html template is called like this it works:
$this->template_html = 'emails/custom-payment-reminder-html.php';

When using the file with the email class that sits in the plugin folder, and the html template is called as follows, it does not work:
        //$this->template_html = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/emails/custom-payment-reminder-html.php';

Comment: you have to define plugin dir $plugin_dir = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__); and then $this->template_html = $plugin_dir . 'includes/custom-payment-reminder-html.php'; or w/e the path would be. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/

Answer (score 0):

I think I just found the solution: The template base needs to be set like this (last row):

```
 $this->template_html = 'emails/custom-payment-reminder-html.php';
 $this->template_plain = 'emails/plain/payment-reminder.php';
 $this->template_base = CUSTOM_WC_EMAIL_PATH . 'templates/';
```

Now it actually works! I do not understand though, why it didn't work with the absolute paths I used before.